# How to display partially a WFS layer? (just the content within a box)

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I need to know how to display a WFS layers, but not the whole content, only the part within a rectangle.

I have this code:

```
var SMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Status map", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
        featureType: "states"
    }),
});
SMap.setVisibility(true);
map.addLayers([SMap]);
```

And I also have two coordinates from this code:

```
controlS = new OpenLayers.Control();
OpenLayers.Util.extend(controlS, {
    draw: function () {
        this.box = new OpenLayers.Handler.Box(controlS,
            {"done": this.notice},
            {keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_SHIFT});
            this.box.activate();
    },
    notice: function (bounds) {
        var ll = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.left, bounds.bottom)); 
        var ur = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.right, bounds.top)); 
        alert(ll.lon.toFixed(4) + ", " + 
              ll.lat.toFixed(4) + ", " + 
              ur.lon.toFixed(4) + ", " + 
              ur.lat.toFixed(4));
    }
});
map.addControl(controlS);
```

What can I do to display only the WFS layer's content within the imaginary box formed by 2 pairs of coordinates?

Thanks and regards,
Rafael

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I put the code here because I think it can be very useful.

```
controlS = new OpenLayers.Control();
OpenLayers.Util.extend(controlS, {
    draw: function () {
          this.box = new OpenLayers.Handler.Box(controlS,
              {"done": this.notice},
              {keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_SHIFT});
              this.box.activate();
    },
    notice: function (bounds) {
    var ll = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.left, bounds.bottom)); 
    var ur = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.right, bounds.top)); 
    var SMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Status map", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({ 
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX, 
        value: new OpenLayers.Bounds(ll.lon,ll.lat,ur.lon,ur.lat),
        }),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
        featureType: "states"
        }),
    });
    SMap.setVisibility(true);
    map.addLayers([SMap]);
    }
});
map.addControl(controlS);
```